# CFIF For array variable not always existing

Tags: coldfusion

I am trying to take a session variable and break it up into an array in order to create separate session variables.

What I am trying to do is have one textbox to find the feet and inches of a length. For Example 15.2 would be 15 feet and 2 inches

```
<cfif isDefined("session")
        and structKeyExists(session, 'checkout') 
            and structKeyExists(session.checkout, 'vehicle') 
                and structKeyExists(session.checkout.vehicle, 'ft') >
<cfset Feet = "#session.checkout.vehicle.ft#" />
<cfset FeetArray = listtoarray(Feet, ".") />
<cfdump var="#FeetArray#">
</cfif>
```

I could then use #FeetArray[1]# & #FeetArray[2]# for feet and inches.

Where I am struggling is sometimes inches will not be entered so FeetArray[2] will not be needed sometimes.

I tried using:

```
<cfif isDefined("#FeetArray[2]#")>
<cfif isDefined("FeetArray[2]")>
```

neither of them worked I was just wondering if someone could please guide me in the correct direction!

Comment: The arraylen() function will tell you how many elements are in your array.  Not related to your question, but if you want normal people to give you feet and inches, separate textboxes would be much more intuitive than your approach.

Comment: `isDefined("session")` should always return true; session is a built-in CF scope.

Comment: IsDefined is the wrong function. it is used to verify whether a variable, with the supplied *name*, exists. `FeetArray[2]` is not a variable name. It is a position within your variable. The variable name here is `FeetArray`. To verify the number of elements in an array take a look at the aptly named ArrayLen() function. That said, you could skip the array and use getToken().  It returns an empty string if the specified list element does not exist. Though agreed this does not seem like the most intuitive structure ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the length of array and according to that you can do your coding.

```
<cfif isDefined("session") and structKeyExists(session, 'checkout') and structKeyExists(session.checkout, 'vehicle') and structKeyExists(session.checkout.vehicle, 'ft') >
    <cfset Feet = "#session.checkout.vehicle.ft#" />
    <cfset FeetArray = listToArray(Feet, ".") />
    <cfif arrayLen(FeetArray) EQ 1>
        code when there is feet available
    <cfelse>
        code when there are both feet and inches available
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Tushar what if I wanted to set it up 0'00" Do you know how I could split the entry instead of using a decimal like `<cfset FeetArray = listToArray(Feet, ".") />` Where the first half lets say 15'2" would be 15' FeetArray[1] and 2" would be FeetArray[2] ?

Answer (score 4):

To check if an element in an array exists, use (the poorly-named) [`arrayIsDefined()`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArrayIsDefined) function:

```
<cfif arrayIsDefined(FeetArray, 2)>
```

Please note: you really oughtn't be using tag-based syntax for business logic code like this. Preserve your tags for your views, where they belong.

Comment: Though to be honest, if the array is not needed for other code, I would just use `getToken()` and skip the cfif altogether.

Comment: Ah yeah, good call: didn't see the array originated from a string.

Comment: agreed with your comment on my answer,